# Equations in $\mathbb{P}^n$ cutting out variety set theoretically

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Exercise 3.28.2 in Kollar's *Rational Curves on Algebraic Varieties*.

Suppose $Z\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a subvariety that is purely $k$-dimensional and of degree $d$. Why does a general choice of $f_0,\ldots,f_n\in H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,I_Z(d))$ cut out $Z$ set theoretically?

Edit: I think it suffices to show that all of $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,I_Z(d))$ cuts out $Z$ set theoretically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint. Project $Z$ to a linear subspace of dimension $k + 1$. The image satisfies an equation of degree $ = \deg Z$. Now look at all such projections.